# Xcode How to pass data from one UIviewController to another UIview Subview

Tags: objective-c, ios6, xcode4.5

I have a `UIViewController` (Main VC) into which another `UIView` is loaded as subview when a button is tapped on `MainViewController`. Actually I load a map view as subview in the main view controller. For that purpose I need to pass the coordinate from `MainViewController` to the subview (map view) to create the `annotation` there & then loaded inside the `MainViewController`.

In `MainViewController` the following method loads the subview correctly:

```
-(IBAction)showUserLocation{
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"UserCurrentLocationView" owner:self options:nil];
    UIView *currentLocationView = [nib objectAtIndex:0];

    currentLocationView.frame = CGRectMake(8, 10, currentLocationView.frame.size.width, currentLocationView.frame.size.height);

    [thirdPortion addSubview:currentLocationView]; // thirdPortion is a View Outlet in the Main VC wh
}
```

Here I want to pass a coordinate (lat/lon) to the `UserCurrentLocationView` 's class so that it can prepare the map and I can see the pointed map in the `MainViewController` when `showUserLocation` method is called by a button.

What is the way to set the value of a property that stays on the `UIView` (Subview) from the `MainViewController`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do google, you will find it

Comment: @AnoopVaidya Bother did google but could not find a solution that worked for me :(
What I have done is, created a property in subview and synth it. Then created an object of subview class in the main view class and then set the data of that property using this object. But the subview class is not getting the value that was set from main view controller class.

Comment: It is because either it is not retained/strong. Or a new instance is getting created. And I am not an ios developer, so can't go in deep :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to subclass the `UIView` (I will call it `YourView`) and add a two properties for `long` and `lat`. Then put it as the class for your .xib - file named UserCurrentLocationView.

Then you do the following to set the variables.

```
-(IBAction)showUserLocation{
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"UserCurrentLocationView" owner:self options:nil];
    YourView *currentLocationView = (YourView *)[nib objectAtIndex:0];

    currentLocationView.lon = self.fooValue;
    currentLocationView.lat = self.fooValue2;

    currentLocationView.frame = CGRectMake(8, 10, currentLocationView.frame.size.width, currentLocationView.frame.size.height);

    [thirdPortion addSubview:currentLocationView]; // thirdPortion is a View Outlet in the Main VC wh
}
```

Comment: Here "currentLocationView" is not a object I think. So, "currentLocationView.fooProperty = self.fooValue" wont work

Comment: @NuhilMehdy Sweet! (Note that I edited the variable name 'long' (which is an invalid variable name) in the code above to lon.)